# Android Bitmaps Bayer Patterns

Tags: android, rgb, android-imageview, bitmapfactory

I am attempting to load jpegs into Android using BitmapFactory, however, the images are in a different Bayer Pattern format then Android wants.  Specifically, I have images in a BGGR and RGGB format.  The RGGB formats seem okay, however, BGGR seems to have issues.

Does Android have a method to convert the BGGR Bayer Pattern to RGGB?  Do I need to create a function to convert both to RGB?  Is there such one already out there?

Answer (score 1):

Would it be too much to ask for a smaple of the file format that you are trying to display? Because on my end I have no problems displaying different BGGR Bayer Pattern filtered files using the following code. The code loads and displays the file in an image view.

```
try {
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Resources resources = getApplicationContext().getResources();
InputStream is = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.test_bggr_bayer_file); // this is a bggr    bayer pattern filtered jpeg file.

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
is.close();
imageView1.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
catch (IOException e) {}
```